# A question of hearing

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I thought of this riddle about a year ago. As far as I am concerned there is only one answer. I would be interested to hear of anyone else's take on it.

> Those who already know can't hear.
>   Those who can hear already know.
>   What do you hear?

Comment: I hear nothing so I already know.

Comment: 'White Noise' !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take on it. Maybe not a real answer but just an idea.

I think it is talking about

> Being open or closed minded

Those who already know can't hear.

> If you think you already know something you stop listening

Those who can hear already know.

> If you are listening you are open minded and so you are enlightened and already know

What do you hear?

> I'm listening to other people's answers because I don't think mine is right :p

Comment: YES, I hear you!

Answer (score 5):

Is it:

> Continuous exposure to sounds above 85 dB?
>
> Those who already know can't hear, because they're deaf. Those who can hear, know that it's happening.

Comment: I was thinking of the same thing :)

Comment: Those who can hear know deafness? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Speak up, I can't hear you..

Comment: I meant sounds loud enough to cause deafness, but sure, that too.

Answer (score 5):

I can hear

> **The answer forming in my head**

Those who already know can't hear.

> If you already know the answer you can't solve it

Those who can hear already know.

> I can hear it an now I know it (I hope)

Comment: I like that too

Comment: But its not the answer

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> Deafness?

Those who already know can't hear

> Those who know they have deafness can't hear

Those who can hear already know.

> Those who can hear already know they don't have deafness.

What do you hear?

> Everything

Comment: That also works

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> There are two statements about other people. And one question about me.
>  I don't know what the others hear (and I don't care), but I hear a riddle.
>
>  It could also be something like "a surprising solution to a riddle".
>  Those who know won't hear the *surprising* solution - it's not surprising as they already know. Those who hear the surprising solution have just discovered what it is, so they know now.

Comment: Here's another suprise

Comment: Don't read the last page.

Answer (score 1):

What do you hear?

> Nearby **impact/explosion** (e.g. of an artillery shell)? (Resulting in a tinnitus-like ringing, at least in movies).

Those who already know can't hear.

> If you are near enough to the impact/explosion, you won't be able to hear, at least until your ears (brain?) recover.

Those who can hear already know.

> If you are capable of hearing (that is, not deaf), then you'll experience the above effect. If you are already deaf, you may not know what happened.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be

> a spoiler

Those who already know can't hear.

> if you know about something, when you hear it you aren't hearing a spoiler

Those who can hear already know.

> If you can hear a spoiler, you know about it

What do you hear?

> a spoiler?

Or if this was read aloud and I was thinking very literally, I might say -

> "I hear a paradox about hearing and knowing...  :P"

Or if I was being particularly awkward,  I'd say -

> "What was that?!  Speak up!"

Comment: OK, that sort of works.

Comment: By the way, you don't have to yell.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> **Telepathy**

`Those who can hear already know.`

> A communication making-up in my mind, Only I know about it...so I can hear it.

`Those who already know can't hear.`

> The person with whom I was/am having telepathy, not necessarily he/she has to think the same way, but he/she is already a part of the communication.

Comment: Have you been reading my journal?

Comment: No......But for what??? @NONAMEBRAND

Comment: @Grinch answered it

Comment: >!When someone thinks they know something they stop listening

Comment: >! Those who can hear ( open to learning the truth ) already know. When someone realises they don't know everything they listen. What do you hear? HERE ( On earth )

Comment: It is not every time, the person might be looking for a second opinion????

What'say @NONAMEBRAND

Comment: >! People block out truth and are not open to new ideas when they are defending their own ideas. If someone is really looking for a second opinion they can hear because they are willing to leave behind their old way of thinking to create a better paradigm. I am sure there are many answers to this riddle, but I had a specific idea when I created it,

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's:

> Tinnitus. Some believe that the sound/tone/frequency that you hear is possibly 'dying' hair cells in the cochlea. To quote a line from the *Children* *of* *Men*: "**Julian**: You know that ringing in your ears? That 'eeeeeeeeee'? That's the sound of the ear cells dying, like their swan song. Once it's gone you'll never hear that frequency again. Enjoy it while it lasts."

So

> A person who has heard that, no longer can hear that frequency, and those who can still hear the frequency, can still identify the sound of that frequency.  [More info.](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/37468/is-the-ringing-sound-in-the-ears-caused-by-dying-ear-cells)

Comment: So those that can hear, already know. hmm. I suppose that also works.

Answer (score -2):

Answer:

> Sound of Silence

Those who already know can't hear.

> when an deaf person sitting alone in a room which he knows that he hearing sound of silence.

Those who can hear already know.

> when an non-deaf person sitting alone in a room which he knows that he too hearing sound of silence.

What do you hear?

> Sound of Silence

Comment: How do you hear silence?